# How to prevent Atmel Studio gcc 6.3.1 from optimizing 4-byte memcmp() to a 4-byte direct comparison?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, atmelstudio, memcmp

Running Atmel Studio with its provided gcc 6.3.1 to build firmware for an Atmel/Microchip SAMV70 (ARM Cortex-M7) chip.  I have code that compares a 4-byte input array to a 4-byte local array using `memcmp()`.  When compiled with `-O0` to disable optimizations it works fine.  When compiled with `-Os` to optimize for size or with `-O3` for max optimization, the compiler is replacing the `memcmp()` call with a direct 4-byte comparison (verified by examining the disassembly).  Unfortunately the optimization also sometimes moves the local 4-byte array to an unaligned starting address, so while `memcmp()` would work fine the direct comparison triggers a `HardFault` due to unaligned access.

In my opinion this is 100% a compiler optimization bug (possibly gcc, possibly something Atmel added), but I'm stuck with the provided compiler so updating isn't an option.  So here's my actual question: Is there a way to keep optimizations enabled but disable this particular optimization?  Otherwise I'm stuck forcing the local 4-byte arrays to be 4-byte aligned or finding some other workaround.

Compiler version:
`gcc version 6.3.1 20170620 (release) [ARM/embedded-6-branch revision 249437] (Atmel build: 508)`

Here's an example function that could trigger the fault:

```
bool example(uint8_t *input_data)
{
    uint8_t local_data[4] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };

    return (memcmp(input_data, local_data, 4) == 0);
}
```

My code is always passing in a 4-byte-aligned `input_data` so that's not an issue, but once again it's bad form for the compiler optimizations to take that for granted.

Comment: How about passing it `-mno-unaligned-access`?

Comment: `ARM Cortex-M7` That would be `-mcpu=cortex-m7  -mthumb` compiler options? Can you post the assembly for full `example` function?

Comment: FYI unaligned access is allowed by default for ARMv7-M according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html So try the option from my previous comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Wow.  It blows my mind that unaligned access is allowed for ARMv7-M but not for 6 or 8.  I'm curious what led to that decision.  Regardless, I think you nailed it.  Adding `-mno-unaligned-access` seems to be working during my initial testing.

Comment: I think it's is up to MMU to trap the unaligned accesses, while Armv7 itself supports it. Do you have MMU enabled? Do you set up the page tables yourself?

Comment: Actually here it is, just a control bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574482/unaligned-memory-access-in-arm-v7

Comment: it is strange it does not optimize it out - https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fy2zu2

Comment: @P__J__ Atmel Studio might have some patched version of gcc...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do not think so. But even forced version: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/J9GXXl uses only ldr instructions which do not require alignment

Comment: @P__J__ Well, it is definitely some Atmel specific version per OP: *gcc version 6.3.1 20170620 (release) [ARM/embedded-6-branch revision 249437] (**Atmel build: 508**)*. Maybe the OP should include the resulting assembly code for the full picture

Comment: Ok I get it now.  ARMv7-M allows some unaligned accesses by default.  This can be disabled (trapping unaligned accesses) via CCR bit 3 (UNALIGN_TRP).  However, that bit is clear on my system so that's not trapping.  BUT, the MPU is configuring this region of memory to Strongly Ordered, which according to the ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual *must* always be naturally aligned.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - You know your stuff!  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Please make this an answer, and Andrew, please mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question since Eugene didn't post an official answer:

From the **gcc ARM options**:

> By default unaligned access is disabled for all pre-ARMv6, all ARMv6-M
>   and for ARMv8-M Baseline architectures, and enabled for all other
>   architectures.

That means unaligned access *is* allowed by default for ARMv7-M.  It turns out this makes sense, because from the **ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual**:

> The following data accesses support unaligned addressing, and only
>   generate alignment faults when the CCR.UNALIGN_TRP bit is set to 1,
>   see Configuration and Control Register:
>
> • Non halfword-aligned LDR{S}H{T} and STRH{T}.
>
> • Non halfword-aligned TBH.
>
> • Non word-aligned LDR{T} and STR{T}.

Which means that ARMv7-M supports a limited set of unaligned accesses.  *However*, it does not support *all* unaligned accesses:

> The following data accesses always generate an alignment fault:
>
> • Non halfword-aligned LDREXH and STREXH.
>
> • Non word-aligned LDREX and STREX.
>
> • Non word-aligned LDRD, LDMIA, LDMDB, POP, LDC, VLDR, VLDM, and VPOP.
>
> • Non word-aligned STRD, STMIA, STMDB, PUSH, STC, VSTR, VSTM, and
>   VPUSH.

And also:

> Accesses to Strongly Ordered and Device memory types must always be
>   naturally aligned

So here's the failure condition that prompted me to ask the initial question:

1. gcc with optimization enabled was replacing a 4-byte `memcmp()` with a direct comparison, which *is* allowed by default, because unaligned accesses are allowed by default.  So that is not a compiler bug.
2. The area of flash memory that contained the data for that `memcmp()` was located in an MPU segment that was declared `Strongly Ordered`, which does *not* support unaligned access.  Thus when the `memcmp()` was replaced with a direct compare, and the data fell on an unaligned address, the compare was triggering a `HardFault`.

The fix, which Eugene got correct in his initial comment, is to add `-mno-unaligned-access` to the compiler options.  In my case this still allowed the compiler to replace the `memcmp()` with a direct 4-byte comparison but it also forced the data to be 4-byte aligned, allowing the compare to succeed without triggering a fault condition.